# How are closed form solutions for eigenvalues constructed from sines and cosines?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For example a size N 3-point finite difference scheme has eigenvalues $\lambda_j = 2+cos(j\pi/(N+1))$. How is this determined?

I know the Gershgorin circle theorem, but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: The best answer here is to just plug in the eigenvectors